# Tracial states on $C_\text{r}^\ast(\mathbf{D}_\infty)$, $\mathbf{D}_\infty$ being the infinite dihedral group

Tags: group-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, dihedral-groups

Let $\mathbf{D}_\infty$ be the infinite dihedral group, i.e. the group generated by two elements $s$ and $t$ with $s^2=t^2 =e$ which are free with respect to each other. Consider the reduced group $C^\ast$-algebra $C_\text{r}^\ast (\mathbf{D}_\infty)$. There exist two canonical tracial states on this $C^\ast$-algebra, namely the state $\tau$ with $\tau(1)=1$ and $\tau(\lambda_s)=\tau(\lambda_t)=0$ and (since $\mathbf{D}_\infty$ is amenable) the character coming from the trivial representation of the group $\mathbf{D}_\infty$ (i.e. the corresponding state maps $1\mapsto1$, $\lambda_s\mapsto1$, $\lambda_t \mapsto 1$). Of course convex combinations of these two states are also tracial, but are these all the tracial states? If no, is there a complete description of all tracial states on $C_\text{r}^\ast(\mathbf{D}_\infty)$? How do they look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

G. K. Pedersen  proved that  $C^*(D_\infty )$ is isomorphic to the subalgebra of $C([-1, 1], M_2)$ formed by all
continuous functions
$$
  f:[-1,1]\to M_2,
  $$
such that $f(-1)$ and $f(1)$ are diagonal, via an isomorphism taking the two generators $s$ and $t$ to the functions
$f_s$ and $f_t$ defined by
$$
  f_s(x) = \pmatrix{ 1 & 0 \cr 0 & -1},
  \quad \text {and} \quad
  f_t(x) = \pmatrix {x & \sqrt{1-x^2} \cr \sqrt{1-x^2} & -x}.
  $$

If $\mu $ is any probability measure on $[-1, 1]$ then the functional
$$
  \tau (f) = \frac 12\int_{-1}^1 \text{tr}(f(x))\,  d\mu (x)
  $$
is a trace.  There are four other traces on this algebra, actually characters, not covered by the  above class of
examples, given by
$$
  \tau ^-_{1}(f) = f(-1)_{1, 1},
  $$
$$
  \tau ^-_{2}(f) = f(-1)_{2, 2},
  $$
$$
  \tau ^+_{1}(f) = f(1)_{1, 1},
  $$
$$
  \tau ^+_{2}(f) = f(1)_{2, 2},
  $$
so there are many more traces  than the ones described by the OP.  On the other hand,  I believe the above span all
traces of    $C^*(D_\infty )$.